# Handling Facebook registration via my Facebook application - using nodejs everyauth

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, express, everyauth

We have Facebook authentication integrated into our User Accounts system (nodejs, express) using **everyauth**.

What is done now (in pseudo code):

```
everyauth
  .facebook
    .appId('....')
    .appSecret('.....')
    .findOrCreateUser( 
      function (session, accessToken, accessTokenExtra, fbUserMetadata) {
      ...
      }
    .redirectPath('/internal/facebook');
```

Authentication works perfectly.
The issue is when going through this flow:

1. User does not have Facebook cookies for his User Agent now (User is
   not logged in into Facebook).
2. User invokes authentication via Facebook (**/auth/facebook** service of everyauth is called)
3. Facebook "Login/Sign in" page is loaded. User wants to create new facebook account and select "Sign up for Facebook".
4. User finishes with registration details and then should confirm his Facebook account registration via our App by clicking the link in the mail he just received.
5. So user goes to his mail, click the link and -
   **he is redirected to the root - "/" - of our User-Account.** - which is a web-service with no UI that provides User-Account service to different application...

#### Questions are following :

1. How can we get the user after he is signed up for Facebook via our Application? **findOrCreateUser()** is not called in this scenario.
2. How can we override the behavior of redirecting to "/" of our App after user is signed up to Facebook via our App (after successful user registration)?

Comment: I don't think the issue is with everyauth but with facebook itself

Comment: Seems found something sad :[https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/issues/44](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/issues/44).Looks like  **everyauth** does not support Facebook Registration form

Comment: i would suggest to go for passport.js instead of everyauth.